# Como agrupar un query por doble condición?

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo un problema para obtener esta consulta.

Tengo una tabla llamada time_entry que se ve más o menos así:

| time_entry |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id_ticket | id_ticket | timer_running | agent |
| 1 | 60 | 1 | rick |
| 2 | 70 | 0 | ana |
| 3 | 70 | 0 | rick |
| 4 | 80 | 1 | rick |

lo que necesito es obtener todos los **id_ticket** que impliquen al menos una vez a un **agent** y en donde la sumatoria de la columna **timer_running** que estén en false (0) sea igual a la cantidad de entradas del mismo id_ticket. (que todo timer_running estén en false)

para el caso particular de arriba (evaluando al agente 'rick') el retorno del query debería ser:

| time_entry |
| --- |
| id_ticket |
| 70 |

porque es el único ticket en donde todas sus entries están en 0 y 'rick' también está participando.

lo que hice fue:

```
SELECT x.id_ticket 
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        id_ticket,
        SUM(CASE WHEN timer_running = 0 and agent_id = 'rick' THEN 1 END) AS number_time_entries_stopped , 
        COUNT(timer_running) AS total_entries
    FROM time_entry 
    GROUP BY id_ticket
) AS x
WHERE x.number_time_entries_stopped = total_entries
```

pero no he logrado contabilizar ya que al parecer me está agrupando también por la columna agent.

muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El escenario:

```
Create Table time_Entry
             (
             id            Int
           , id_ticket     Int
           , timer_running Int
           , agent_id      VarChar(20)
             );
Go

Insert Into time_Entry(id
                     , id_ticket
                     , timer_running
                     , agent_id)
Values
       ( 1, 60, 1, 'rick' ),
       ( 2, 70, 0, 'ana' ),
       ( 3, 70, 0, 'rick' ),
       ( 4, 80, 1, 'rick' );
Go
```

El problema está en que si utilizas el case when .. id_Agent='rick' solo te evalúa para la suma la fila donde existe ese agente, y por tanto la cuenta no es 1

```
SELECT 
        id_ticket,
        SUM(CASE WHEN timer_running = 0 and agent_id = 'rick' THEN 1 END) AS number_time_entries_stopped , 
        COUNT(timer_running) AS total_entries
    FROM time_entry 
    GROUP BY id_ticket
```

[image: Resultado]

La condición de Rick, tiene que ser aplicada a las filas.

```
SELECT x.id_ticket 
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        id_ticket,
        SUM(CASE WHEN timer_running = 0  THEN 1 else 0 END) AS number_time_entries_stopped  ,
        COUNT(timer_running) AS total_entries
    FROM time_entry 
    where agent_id = 'rick'
    GROUP BY id_ticket
) AS x
WHERE x.number_time_entries_stopped = total_entries
```

[image: Resultado 2]